# Non-deterministic object reference bug in PHP 5.3.X

Tags: php, php-5.3

As of yesterday (perhaps after a recent PHP update?), I'm getting some very strange non-deterministic bugs in php 5.3.3. These appear in our production server in PHP 5.3.2 as well.

The errors essentially amount to `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Attempt to assign property of non-object'` in various parts of the code base. Generally, the error line is something like: `$this->foo = $bar` in a `__construct()` call.

`$this` is not found in the constructor?!

I have no idea what is going on. Any ideas? Is this possibly a regression of this bug?: http://bugs.php.net/31525

**Edit**: I should mention, refreshing the script after a little while, with absolutely no changes to the code, makes it work again. Hence non-deterministic.

**Edit 2**: Furthermore, while PHP is set to log even the tiniest of errors, and *is* logging other errors as they occur, this error is not logged in the log file. This brings me to think we are looking at a PHP engine dependency error.

Comment: On my local box, there isn't any: http://pastie.org/pastes/1300493/text?key=79mmr7dmm10qi4cvy6kvg

Comment: Show the constructor...  Actually, show the whole class if you can...  Does it always happen on the same class?  Or does the error wander?  Do you have full back-traces to be sure the error isn't being triggered on another line, but displaying there (like inside of a magic-method perhaps)?

Comment: The error started happening in various places as of this morning, but it consistently occurs here: http://pastie.org/private/93cnqeowtwzawudurgrg9g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it looks to be a bug...

- [An instance of it happening with Zend_Config](http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-components-13/core-infrastructure-19/warning-attempt-assign-property-non-object-zend_config-5469.html)
- [A possibly related issue with symfony](http://www.mail-archive.com/symfony-users@googlegroups.com/msg31165.html)
- And a few others (Searching for it is pretty useless since a fair number of sites throw that error.  So it's hard to discern valid instances from generic errors)

Here's some relevant bug reports:

- [52083](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52083)
- [50027](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50027)

Comment: Yep, this confirms my suspicions. We're going to install the latest snapshot of 5.3.x, and will post our progress here. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what platform are you on (32-bit x86?  or 64-bit x64)?

Comment: Linux karan-desktop 2.6.35-22-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 16 20:36:48 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux (32 bit) and the production server is running 64 bit (Linux cyphontech 2.6.32-25-server #45-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 16 20:06:58 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Comment: That's interesting since the second bug suggests it's a 64 bit issue.  I'd suggest trying the snapshot.  Either way (if it works or does not) post a reply to one of the bugs with the associated info (I'd suggest `50027`), and then a reply to the other indicating that they are likely related issues...

Comment: Will do, snapshot is currently compiling.

Comment: Just an update, we have updated to php 5.3.4-dev, compiling from the snapshot. Note, the build forces the php.ini file to be in /usr/local/lib for some reason