# PHP 5.3 Bug #50027 $this becomes a non-object - is it fixed for windows package?

Tags: php

I need php 5.3 but I need windows also. I cant run any project now because of this bug.

Does anybody know how to fix it in windows.

I read and tried this one - http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50027.

And have similar problem like here - [intermittent 'Attempt to assign property of non-object' on requests / unable to set object properties via $this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015711/intermittent-attempt-to-assign-property-of-non-object-on-requests-unable-to-s/5066268#5066268)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which precise PHP version are you currently using?  The bug comments imply that it could have been fixed in 5.3.5 or the upcoming 5.3.6.  [Here are the latest 5.3.6 Release Candidate builds for Windows](http://windows.php.net/qa/).

Comment: I have 5.3.3 Trying to setup the new one.
Thanks

Comment: Be sure to check with php.net late next week, 5.3.6 RC3 is supposed to be the last release candidate before 5.3.6 final, which you'll want to move to when it's officially out.

Comment: PHP 5.3.6 has now been release FYI